# Visual Studio WPF C# | OnPropertyChange | unclear behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm working on a plugin that I didn't start developing and there is a behaviour that I don't understand.

Code:

**MAINWINDOW.xaml**

TABLE1 and TABLE2 structures

```
<DataGrid ...>
   ...
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="title" Width="Auto">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MYPROPERTY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ...
</DatGrid>
```

**MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs**

```
      private void MYCLASS_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
LineY    if (!_isInitialising) { Recalculate(); }
      }
```

**OTHER C# FILE**

```
namespace NAME
{
   public class MYCLASS : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      ...
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      ...
      public double MYPROPERTY
      {
         get {...}
         set {...; OnPropertyChanged("MYPROPERTY");}
      }
      ...
      public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
LineX       handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Behaviour:
I have a first table TABLE1 in MAINWINDOW.xaml.
When I change MYPROPERTY in TABLE1 it calls the OnPropertyChange (LineX) and then jumps to VOID MYCLASS_CHANGED in MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs (LineY) and I don't undertand why this link happens, is someone able to explain it or tell me what to look when debugging (I'm not an actual programmer) ?

I have a second table TABLE2 in MAINWINDOW.xaml.
When I change MYPROPERTY in TABLE2 it calls the OnPropertyChange but it doesn't jump to the other function. I would like to in order to call some functions inside MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs

Comment: Maybe MYCLASS_Changed is explicitly attached to the PropertyChanged event of the view model of TABLE1. We can't tell from the code you are showing. Look through the code for occurences of MYCLASS_Changed.

Comment: ok i saw the following line before but i just understand now the meaning - and given that was in a function not called directly when changing the value in the table i thought wasnt useful but actually is the solution at my question... thx

MYELEMENT.PropertyChanged += MYCLASS_Changed; (when creating elements)

Answer (score -1):

Your code appears to be structured as Model - View - ViewModel pattern (MVVM).

Your ViewModel cannot/should not access the View directly hence the use of `Binding` this instructs the .NET framework to expect an event trigger in which the new value of the bound parameter is sent - this is the `PropertyChangedEvent`. If declared "OneWay" then this is from the ViewModel to the View, if "BothWays" then entry of data on the View will trigger a change within the ViewModel property.

MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs jointly make up the View (hence the `partial` declaration within MainWindow.xaml.cs).

MainWindow.xaml.cs is what is referred to as the "code behind" file for MainWindow.xaml.

In MVVM the View displays data that has been presented/retrieved/calculated by the ViewModel which in turn gets its base data structure from the Model.

There is some overlap in function, often you will see no Model (all of the data being held within the ViewModel) or some business logic within the code behind file (rather than just within the ViewModel).

It would appear that, in your code, you have the `OnPropertyChangedEvent` from the ViewModel triggering the `MYCLASS_Changed` event handler within your code behind file.

I suspect that this is related to your data trigger set by `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` but can't say for certain with the code that you have posted.

Comment: Actually was not made following MVVM rules and all functions are inside the MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs
this is how the DataGrid is set but it's the same for both TABLES (except for the Name):
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="TABLE1" GridLinesVisibility="None" ColumnWidth="*" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" Style="{StaticResource DataGridWithColours}"> (selectionchanged have just a function that doesnt work in this case so doesnt do anything)

Comment: With `public class MYCLASS : INotifyPropertyChanged` it looks like a ViewModel, plus your View code uses `Binding` to one of its properties which reinforces that argument. In any case the event triggering will still follow the course that I mentioned.

Comment: ok i saw the following line before but i just understand now the meaning - and given that was in a function not called directly when changing the value in the table i thought wasnt useful but actually is the solution at my question... thx

MYELEMENT.PropertyChanged += MYCLASS_Changed; (when creating elements)